# How to hide content behind a transparent header through css, js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've made an header composed of a top transparent section with logo and social link plus a navbar that have a padding from top. [this is the transparent header that i've made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G9r3.jpg). On the navbar i have some anchor and it work well (i've added the padding as requested in bootstrap then it work fine). The problem is that when i scroll the page, the content go behind my header. [look here what is happening now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOmaH.jpg). This isn't what i would like to have. I've read a ton of post about similar situation but i've not find a solution. Is there a javascript workaround or a tecnique to hide the content div when they pass over the navbar??? How can i achieve this? I'd really like to save the transparent top header! Thanks a lot and regards!

Comment: Did you forget to add the picture?

Comment: yeah sorry i've added it...it's my first question sorry! ;)

Comment: Do you want it to be transparent until someone scrolls the page? Then what do you want to happen?

Comment: why do you want the transparent top header? Just add the background that matches the underlying main content's background.

Comment: i would like that when i scroll the page, the header remains the same and nothing is showed under it!

Comment: @VladimirM then you advise me to add to the header the same background?

Comment: @FedericoAngeloni yes. so that you dont have to make it transparent to have the top of the photo shown.

Comment: it can surely work! but how can i center the image in the same way of the body's background-image? i've tried to set the same background image with the same parameter (no-repeat center fixed) but it isn't alligned. I think that is due to the different div size!

Comment: I've found the solution! The best is to add to the header the same background image of the body, and then edit it with css, setting the background with the same parameter (in my case "no-repeat center fixed") and adding background-size:cover; In this way the trick is done!!! thanks you very much for the hints! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a bit old, but since it was something I was working on myself I thought I would share a simple solution.

```js
window.addEventListener(
  "scroll",
  function hideContent() {
    var h = document.getElementById("gallery");

    h.style.clipPath = "inset(" + this.window.pageYOffset + "px 0% 0% 0%)";
  },
  false
);
```

```css
body {
  /* Replace with a background image if you like */
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(119, 0, 255), rgb(0, 225, 255));
}

#header-box {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.gallery-box {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 800px;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

.box p {
  font-size: 34px;
  text-align: left;
}

#lorem-one {
  background-color: gray;
}

#lorem-two {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}

#lorem-three {
  background-color: seagreen;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <title>Sample Code - Feel free to copy and use</title>

  <meta name="description" content="Hiding Content Behind Transparent Header" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header-box">
    <p>My Transparent Header</p>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery-box" id="gallery">
    <div class="box" id="lorem-one">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla at massa diam. Duis tempus finibus efficitur. Sed nibh arcu, convallis eu massa quis, efficitur fringilla nisl. Maecenas risus est, ullamcorper quis magna eget, euismod vestibulum mi. Ut lacinia
        eros vel nulla sollicitudin, a ultrices orci commodo. Donec ac justo vel eros aliquet egestas. Donec at sem non nulla tincidunt venenatis scelerisque eget risus. Sed tortor leo, lacinia viverra enim sit amet, tincidunt accumsan sem. Integer maximus
        augue tempus lectus consectetur, eget aliquet lorem feugiat.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="box" id="lorem-two">
      <p>
        Donec volutpat, ipsum eget pretium congue, diam mauris scelerisque orci, a vehicula felis lectus in risus. Nulla facilisi. Integer non sollicitudin nulla. Fusce vehicula ultricies dictum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra,
        per inceptos himenaeos. Proin a semper risus, id bibendum neque. Sed condimentum condimentum sapien, vitae aliquet magna interdum ac. Sed tempor dui sed neque tristique posuere. Nunc vel rhoncus augue. Vestibulum quis aliquet purus, eu cursus
        odio.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="box" id="lorem-three">
      <p>
        Sed tristique dolor id nulla eleifend eleifend. Nam et turpis sed nisl elementum posuere. Suspendisse est metus, dictum ut sapien in, lacinia placerat libero. Nullam iaculis felis ut tortor porta sollicitudin. Fusce at est porttitor, congue tellus in,
        euismod arcu. Nam vulputate vulputate aliquet. Ut commodo consequat magna, eget imperdiet urna condimentum eu. Vivamus sagittis mauris quis nisi tempus, nec interdum nisi tempus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
        fames ac turpis egestas. Integer tempus eu tortor at mattis. Nam lacus magna, aliquet sed facilisis porta, consequat id eros. Pellentesque gravida nibh mi, a gravida lorem vestibulum ac.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the simplest solution without JS or Jquery.

1) Be sure that your header is contained into a specific div and set a class for it. example:

`<div class="content_header">...</div>`

2) Assuming that you've already set a background-image for your body (or for the div that contain your content), add this in your css:

```
.content_header {
position: fixed;
background: url("...same of body's background image") no-repeat center fixed (same shorthand parameter, if any);
background-size: cover;}
```

3) In this way you'll have a background image that will make a fake "transparent header" effect, and you will resolve the problem of scrolling content that appear behind the transparent header.

I hope that you'll find this useful, and i'd like to thanks the guys that have given me the hints ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your scrolling content into an element `<div class="content">...</div>` and style it overflow hidden:

```
.content {
  overflow: hidden; /* or "auto" or "scroll" */
}
```

this way everything outside the content element will be hidden.

if this helped you, fine :)
if not I may help you better if you would post an example page.

Comment: Thanks @FirePanther i've tried your solution, i've made my scrolling content in a div, and update the css, but it seems that isn't working. The content is again behind the transparent header!

Comment: could you maybe post the url to your webpage or export the not working part? so i could integrate the overflow part into it. the div should be under the logo, it wouldn't work if your logo is position absolute or fixed and the content div is under it, you would need `margin-top: {logoheight}px;` or something like that for this

Comment: the header is formed by a top header with logo and social button + a navbar. All the header is fixed. I've already added a margin top, and this have solved the "starting point" of my content. The problem was when i scroll the page. Also adding "overflow:hidden" it continue to appear behind the header, and since it is transparent it is shown. I've solved the problem adding the same image of the body as background (see my solution below)! With this trick i've achieved the same result and now when i scroll the page, the content is hidden behind the image! ;) thanks a lot!